Angular compilation initialization failed [plugin angular-compiler]
Hi i am trying to build Angular project with ng build on the my Linux AWS server
when I try to update my project with GitHub actions it's giving error on the below but when I delete the project and redownload it, from GitHub the pipeline successfully working idk what it's the problem on my project.
Here the problem and my package.json
ng build
out: #12 1.914 - Building...
out: #12 1.914 
out: #12 7.677 Application bundle generation failed. [5.760 seconds]
out: #12 7.677 
out: #12 7.709 ✘ [ERROR] Angular compilation initialization failed. [plugin angular-compiler]
out: #12 7.709 
out: #12 7.709   Error: Cannot resolve type entity i1.BidiModule to symbol
out: #12 7.709       at reflectTypeEntityToDeclaration (file:///app/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/bundles/chunk-6IQBXGRH.js:727:11)
out: #12 7.709       at extraReferenceFromTypeQuery (file:///app/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/bundles/chunk-7OQMTKOE.js:1472:26)
out: #12 7.709       at file:///app/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/bundles/chunk-7OQMTKOE.js:1467:12
out: #12 7.709       at Array.map (<anonymous>)
out: #12 7.709       at extractReferencesFromType (file:///app/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/bundles/chunk-7OQMTKOE.js:1463:23)
out: #12 7.709       at DtsMetadataReader.getNgModuleMetadata (file:///app/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/bundles/chunk-7OQMTKOE.js:1669:16)
out: #12 7.709       at MetadataDtsModuleScopeResolver.resolve (file:///app/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/bundles/chunk-7OQMTKOE.js:3886:37)
out: #12 7.709       at MetadataDtsModuleScopeResolver.resolve (file:///app/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/bundles/chunk-7OQMTKOE.js:3908:33)
out: #12 7.709       at StandaloneComponentScopeReader.getScopeForComponent (file:///app/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/bundles/chunk-LHQ7WPU2.js:2678:52)
out: #12 7.709       at CompoundComponentScopeReader.getScopeForComponent (file:///app/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/bundles/chunk-7OQMTKOE.js:3851:27)

my package.json file
    {
  "name": "ecommerce-angular",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test",
    "serve:ssr:Ecommerce-Angular": "node dist/ecommerce-angular/server/server.mjs"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^17.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^17.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^17.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^17.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^17.0.0",
    "@angular/material": "^17.3.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^17.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^17.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^17.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^17.0.0",
    "@angular/ssr": "^17.0.1",
    "@microsoft/signalr": "^7.0.14",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "jquery": "^3.7.1",
    "lazyload-image": "^2.2.0",
    "mime": "^4.0.1",
    "ng-lazyload-image": "^9.1.3",
    "ngx-toastr": "^18.0.0",
    "rxjs": "~7.8.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.14.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^17.0.1",
    "@angular/cli": "^17.3.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^17.0.0",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.17",
    "@types/jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.5.29",
    "@types/node": "^18.18.0",
    "@types/slick-carousel": "^1.6.40",
    "jasmine-core": "~5.1.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.2.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "typescript": "~5.2.2",
    "vite": "^4.5.0"
  }
}

I am trying to update my project with GitHub actions.

npm install @angular/cdk --save

It will solve problem, works for ng18
